# How to share arguments between two Mutation classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

In my Rails API project using `graphql-ruby`, I have two Mutations that stands for two slightly different flows. They share a lot of arguments and I would like to keep it DRY, avoiding repeating the similar arguments, so when we change them, we don't accidentally forget to change the other.

I was wondering how I could solve this problem without falling into the *[boolean/flag](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html) [trap](https://medium.com/@amlcurran/clean-code-the-curse-of-a-boolean-parameter-c237a830b7a3)* resulting in a tangled implementation.

I could use concepts of inheritance or composition, but how to do it ?

```rb
module Mutations
  class CreateThing < BaseMutation
    argument :argument1, Float, required: true
    argument :argument2, Float, required: true
    argument :argument3, Float, required: true
    argument :specific_arg, String, required: false

    def resolve(**kwargs)
      new_thing = kwargs.merge(
        assignee:                 current_user
      )

      Things::Create.call(company: current_company, new_thing: new_thing)
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
module Mutations
  class CreateFlexibleThing < BaseMutation
    argument :argument1, Float, required: true
    argument :argument2, Float, required: true
    argument :argument3, Float, required: true
    argument :other_arg, String, required: false
    argument :link, String, required: true

    def resolve(**kwargs)
      new_thing = kwargs.merge(
        assignee:                 current_user
      )

      Things::Create.call(company: current_company, new_thing: new_thing)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way I found is using mixins.

With the help of [`SuperModule`](https://github.com/AndyObtiva/super_module) or [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html), I think it yields a pretty clean code.

`app/graphql/mutations/create_thing.rb`

```rb
module Mutations
  class CreateThing < BaseMutation

    include Mixins::CreateThingArguments 

    argument :specific_arg, String, required: false

    def resolve(**kwargs)
      new_thing = kwargs.merge(
        assignee:                 current_user
      )

      Things::Create.call(company: current_company, new_thing: new_thing)
    end
  end
end
```

`app/graphql/mutations/create_flexible_thing.rb`

```rb
module Mutations
  class CreateFlexibleThing < BaseMutation

    include Mixins::CreateThingArguments 

    argument :other_arg, String, required: false
    argument :link, String, required: true

    def resolve(**kwargs)
      new_thing = kwargs.merge(
        assignee:                 current_user
      )

      Things::Create.call(company: current_company, new_thing: new_thing)
    end
  end
end
```

`app/graphql/mutations/mixins/create_thing_arguments.rb`

```rb
module Mutations::Mixins
  class CreateThingArguments
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    include GraphQL::Types # Make sure to include types

    included do
      argument :argument1, Float, required: true
      argument :argument2, Float, required: true
      argument :argument3, Float, required: true
    end
  end
end
```